# S3 Fatal error: Failed to connect to proxy URL: "Proxy url"

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

Good Afternoon,

I have been trying to remove some files from S3, last week I did not have any issues accessing my s3 bucket however now any s3 cmd fails with the error message above, I cant even run aws s3 ls now with out seeing that error. Nothing changed in the environment over the weekend and the proxy is functioning where could I strt troubleshooting this issue?

Best Regards,
Zach

Comment: *What* error message?

Comment: The error message is simply: S3 Fatal error: Failed to connect to proxy URL: "Proxy url" however I think this is a misleading error message since the proxy is functioning and was not an issue last week with nothing changing.

Comment: Update: I deployed a new ec2 instance and attempted the s3 cmds again and was successful on the new instance but still not on the old instance, nothing should be different between the two but im not sure where I would start to troubleshoot with the original instance.